# Hover and Click action on same object on touch devices

Tags: touch-screen, hover, timeline

I am building a timeline widget which has 2 interactions on web.

- Hover to see a particular duration's details like duration, start time, assigned name.
- Click to edit details of the timeline

However, the primary use of the timeline widget is on a tablet (touch device). What could be some ways to achieve these interactions on a touch device?

Comment: The combination of touch screens and hover/tooltips has been explored quite a few times on this website. See e.g. [What are some alternatives to "hover" on touch-based devices?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-are-some-alternatives-to-hover-on-touch-based-devices) and linked questions.

Comment: Also, using hover to display important information won't meet accessibility standards. How can someone who can't use a mouse get to see this information? Can you access it via keyboard?